# Error in this program for int array in two different situations behaves differently

Tags: java, arrays, out-of-memory

Error in this program for int array
Can anyone explain why these two cases behave differently?

```
class MainOutOfMemoryError {
    /*
    case1:doesn't give me any error
    static final int s = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // we cant declare local variables as static
        int[] i = new int[s];
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    */

    // case2:gives error    
    static final int SIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        int[] i = new int[SIZE];
        System.out.println(SIZE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would allocating an array of 2 million `int`s give an `OutOfMemoryError`?  That's only 8 MB.

Comment: in Case1,it is showing sopln(s) prints 0 but in case 2 it prints actual Size ,WHY ?

Comment: Which case really gives an error? In your code snippet the case 2 shouldn't give any error.

Comment: @RameshRaj Then that's not an out of memory. Could you please edit your post with your comment as title. That is the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

From your comment

> in Case1,it is showing sopln(s) prints 0 but in case 2 it prints actual Size ,WHY ?

In your first case, integer overflow happened and the result of s is `0`

```
static final int s = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

// s value is 0 because of overflow
```

That is kind of writing

```
int[] i = new int[0];
```

Where as in second case the result `s` is `2097152` a valid integer and you run out of memory while allocation of  memory for integers in array.

So you are trying to do

```
int[] i = new int[2097152];
```

Which try to allocate the memory  `67108864` bits.

I'm kind of clues here that, what makes you out of memory since that bits are equals to `8.388608MB`

Answer (score 1):

The `int` `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` is actually `0` due to `int` overflow.

`int` arithmetic works modulo `2^32`. Since `1024 = 2^10`, the true mathematical value of that product is `2^50`. Since `50 > 31`, `s == 0`.

In the first case you are allocating an array of length 0. In the second case it has length over 2 million.

Comment: Thank you for not making it seem like 0 is the magical overflow value! If the OP had set it to 1025*1025*1025*1025*1025 it would have come out completely different ...

Comment: @dcsohl Actually my original answer did imply that. I did a quick edit before the downvotes came in!

Comment: I saw. :) But everybody else is saying "it overflowed so it came out to 0" without explaining why. Just wanted to thank you for that.

Comment: It still could get misinterpreted. It’s not only that `50 > 31`, but also that `2⁵⁰ / 2³²` is *exactly* `2⁽⁵⁰⁻³²⁾`, no remainder, thus `2⁵⁰ % 2³² == 0`

Answer (score 0):

For your first example, `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024`, Google calculator gives `1.1258999e+15`. The Java [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) tutorial says (in part)

> `int`: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of 2^31-1

According to Google calculator, the maximum value of an `int` is thus 2147483647. Which means your value overflows `int`. That's why it worked.

If you test it like,

```
int i = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
System.out.println(i);
```

You'll see that the result is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the opposite: case 1 gives an error and the 2nd doesn't:

It is not the array that is causing the memory overflow but the variable SIZE which is an int with a max value of around 2 billion, change it to long and the problem is solved.